# Combine multiple columns in latex

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to build a table with a header similar to this, and combine all columns and write text below that.

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{The Caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{WP Number}      & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{WP1} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{WP Title}       & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Foo} &
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Start-End Date} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Baz} \\ \hline
foo bar baz are related to bar baz and band
%& & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I tried to find examples on the web to show a figure of this, but I failed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the alignment of the first row shouldn't differ from the regular, there is no need for all those `\multicolumn` commands. And to combine all the columns to a single cell in a row you might use `\multicolumn`...

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\caption{The Caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
\hline
WP Number & WP1 & WP Title & Foo & Start-End Date & Baz\\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{foo bar baz are related to bar baz and band}\\
\hline
foo & bar & baz & bar & foo &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also to visually enhance the table I won't use vertical lines and replace the `\hline`s by `booktabs`'s `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{The Caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\toprule
WP Number & WP1 & WP Title & Foo & Start-End Date & Baz\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{foo bar baz are related to bar baz and band}\\
\midrule
foo & bar & baz & bar & foo & band\\
foo & bar & baz & bar & foo & band\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{foo bar baz are related to bar baz and band}\\
\midrule
foo & bar & baz & bar & foo & band\\
foo & bar & baz & bar & foo & band\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Booktabs version of it looks slick!